# different server response in node js and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

hi i have a simple email check route on my server to realize whether email is registered or not .

this my code on this route in nodejs :

```
    router.post('/mailCheck', async (req, res) => {
  let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (user) return res.status(400).send('User Already Registered.');
  if (!user)return res.status(200).send('Address Can Be Registered.');
});
```

when i send request using postman i get right answers but when i try to send request using axios in react i always get status 200 , status 400 never happens even when email is already in use by another account
this is code in react

```
let st = await axios.post(this.config.api_mailCheck,JSON.stringify({email : e.target.value}))
        console.log(st);
        if(st.status===200){
                this.setState({
                    code block to next step 
                })
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                isDupEmail : true
            })
        }
```

i've compared both request bodies on axios and postman all are the same

disable cors on browser for cross-origin access is applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is because you are trying to stringify your post data.  This is not neccessary with axios and the server is probably getting the email in a different format than you are expecting, so it is not finding a match.

Try this:

```
let st = await axios.post(this.config.api_mailCheck, {email : e.target.value})
        console.log(st);
        if(st.status===200){
                this.setState({
                    code block to next step 
                })
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                isDupEmail : true
            })
        }
```